# Android webview android.widget.CheckedTextView causes crash

Tags: android, webview

I have an app with a webview.
Within that webview there is a form:

```
<select>
 <option value='1'>Something</option>
</select>
```

When the select field is clicked android will invoke android.widget.CheckedTextView

I have found that on some devices this causes a crash (see log below)

So my question is, how can i avoid this crash? 
Maybe it is possible to extend webview and add try{} before android invokes CheckedTextView.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$InvokeListBox$MyArrayListAdapter.getView(WebViewClassic.java:12535)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1142)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4724)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020008
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2265)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:67)
    at android.widget.CheckedTextView.<init>(CheckedTextView.java:58)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_on_mtrl.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000a
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2265)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:977)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2262)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:913)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2262)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: This seems to be one of the root problems: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_btn_radio_material.xml`. Does the file exist?

Comment: Those should be a part of the Android library right ? I am not sure how to locate such files, as they are not in the drawable folder. It seems to be an issue with Android 4.4 or below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if i replaced the following line in build gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

solved the issue.

I am not entirely sure why, but apparently there are some differences in the appcompat versions that does not go well with earlier android versions.